# How to render OpenGL on a live wallpaper (It's way too HARD!)?

Tags: android, opengl-es, live-wallpaper, cube, renderer

So imagine you have and android application (not live wallpaper), and lets say it features a cube rendered in OpenGL with textures and lighting and all that. Now, how would you port that into a live wallpaper? Now i already have a way to do it, but the approach I took somehow will not work on Samsung phones! So i'm wondering how others have done it because obviously other 3D live wallpapers work on Samsung phones. I've tried Robert Green's GLWallpaperService but he provided so little documentation on how it is implemented that i failed to figure out how to utilize it. So here is the question: How can i get a normal opengl app to work as a wallpaper given that it has a Cube.java class and a Renderer.java class, which acts as the renderer of the cube?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robert Green's service is the only way I know of. I've used it for wallpapers that work fine on Samsung devices.

A community project has started to keep the code up to date, and it has examples of how to use it.  See [here](https://github.com/markfguerra/GLWallpaperService).

Comment: Yeah that's what I use (the github version). it's actually pretty easy and it's been succesfully used on live wallpapers available in the market